# EditText with custom background using onDraw

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to have a custom EditText with a custom background which is not possible to draw using drawable XMLs

Here is what I have right now

```
public class EMEditText extends EditText {
    private Bitmap framedBitmap;

    public EMEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(framedBitmap == null) {
            createDrawable(getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        // canvas.drawBitmap(framedBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    private void createDrawable(int width, int height) {
        // create a new bitmap of given size
        Bitmap start = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(start);

        RectF outerRect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        // paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        canvas.drawRoundRect(outerRect, height / 2, height / 2, paint);
        framedBitmap = start;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of compiling your code? Background doesn't show up, it is distorted or what?

Answer (score 2):

What is probably wrong in your code is that you are creating your own `Canvas` object in `createDrawable()` method though `onDraw()` method gives you the right `Canvas` which you should use for your drawings.

So what you probably want is to change `createDrawable(int width, int height)` method to `createDrawable(int width, int height, Canvas c)`. Your code should look like this then:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(framedBitmap == null) {
        createDrawable(getWidth(), getHeight(), canvas);
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    // canvas.drawBitmap(framedBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}

private void createDrawable(int width, int height, Canvas c) {
    // create a new bitmap of given size
    Bitmap start = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    c.setBitmap(start);

    RectF outerRect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    // paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    // paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
    c.drawRoundRect(outerRect, height / 2, height / 2, paint);
    framedBitmap = start;
}
```

As you can see, I changed also the body of your `createDrawable()` method so that it uses `Canvas` from `onDraw()` and sets it's `Bitmap` to the one created by you.